# Excel dates formatted in "YYYY MMM DD 00:00:00.000" need the dates to be in DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to program a macro to convert all dates in a worksheet to go from "2009 APR 01 00:00:00.000" to a date format "dd-mmm-yyyy"? I have a data set that is regularly pulled and all the dates in 40+ columns are basically useless in 2009 APR 01 00:00:00.000, any ideas on how to create this type of macro and be able to share with others using the same data?

Thanks!

Comment: what type of column it is? string?

Comment: where does the data come from? cant the source be modified to pull the data in the format, you need?

Comment: I can't modify the source, unfortunately. The columns have headers and then the dates assoicated with each row. One "date" per cell

Comment: where is Joel when you need him :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your dates are always the same length of string.  Here's one possible solution:

```
orgDate = "2009 APR 01 00:00:00.000"

newDate = mid(orgDate,10,2) & "-" & mid(orgDate,6,3) & "-" & left(orgDate,4)
```

Iterate through each cell with a loop and perform the above string operation, then put newDate back in the cell.

Comment: I'm a total newbie...I'll need to look up what you mean by this... thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
Function GetDateInMyFormat(exampleDate As String) As Date
On Error GoTo e
Dim year As String
Dim month As String
Dim day As String

Dim wantedDate As String

year = Mid(exampleDate, 1, 4)
month = Mid(exampleDate, 6, 3)
day = Mid(exampleDate, 10, 2)

wantedDate = year & "/" & month & "/" & day
GetDateInMyFormat = CDate(wantedDate)
Exit Function

e:

End Function
```

You can create an XLA (XL addin) and add this function as part of XL VBA.
Load the addin using excel's addin dialog box. This way the function will be available to the workbooks.

And, you can use this function on your cells, just like any other function.
Let me know, if you face any issues.

usage: GetDateInMyFormat("2009 apr 01 00:00:00.000")
returns 4/1/2009

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Excel recognizes them as dates, you can just change the cell formatting to the proper date format. Highlight column, right-click -> format cells...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full answer for you, but here's what I would do roughly:

1. Get the range of the entire spreadsheet so you know what you have to iterate through.
2. Iterate through each cell.
3. When on each cell, check if it is a date format already.
4. If cell format is date format already, then use the following code: Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy".
5. If not, then move on the the next cell.

Good luck!